# Lambda function runs for 2 seconds every time but not running the code inside it

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function which is super super basic and it won't run anything inside it. This is pretty much how I start all Lambda functions, as in I handle the event that triggered it and then output 1-2 pieces of data from that event to make sure it works. However when I am doing it now it seems that the function will not run any code. It complete in 2-2.5 seconds every time even if I add a set timeout to 5 seconds. Below is the current iteration of test / setup code. How can I fix this so that it will actually run the function properly and in full?

```
module.exports.email = async (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    let input = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
    let message = JSON.parse(input.Message)
    let companyID = message.companyID
    let email = message.email

    console.log(companyID)
    console.log(email)
    return true
}
```

Edit** Please ignore the settime I guess, it was part of testing if the function would run code or not, I now see it was wrong but that still doesn't explain why the console.log's wouldn't run

Edit 2** Resolved the issue, wasn't a code issue but instead was an AWS one I think since I did a sanity test and it worked with the exact same code that is in the OP here.

Comment: I think remove email from `module.exports.email` and leave module.exports only

Comment: You aren't actually waiting for that timeout. That's not how timeouts are used. The function will close instantly, then some time later your timeout will try to execute.
The other code looks like it can fail if event.Records is unset, or if there is no element zero.

Comment: @SaachiTech Umm??? I can't do that or it won't run, I am using the serverless framework and you have to name the functions when you are having multiple. This isn't something I can remove

Comment: You should [read about how `setTimeout()` works.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: @speciesUnknown Hmm don't use settime often so maybe it's wrong but none the less it should have no impact on the console.log's not running. I know for certain this event has data because I have it in a SNS => 2x SQS and the other SQS has data.

Comment: @Pointy I will but I think the focus shouldn't be on that, it was part of a test to see if code would run or not. It didn't run anything which is why I posted

Comment: What does the passed-in `callback` function do?  The `setTimeout()` won't hurt anything but it will have absolutely no effect either.

Comment: @Pointy It should do nothing, the goal of this post is to figure out why no code runs. I am expecting the console.log's to output data or undefined if no data, it currently does neither. The issue is not the callback nor the settimeout, it is that no code is running at all.

Comment: Step 2: debug the code that's not being invoked.  Step 1: debug the invocation.

Comment: @danh The some of the code not being ran is a console.log. Would that not be the same as logging a literal, ie it logs my variable or it logs undefined? So I just tested logging via `console.log('1')` and it didn't work at all. Something else is wrong here than the console.log and such.